# Multiple destructor calls

Tags: c++, c++11

I ran the following code..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
protected:
    int count=0;
public:
    Base() { cout << "Constructor called" << endl; }
    ~Base() { cout << "Destructor called" << endl; }
    int getCount() {cout << "The count value is " << count << endl;}
    Base operator ++ (int) {count++;  cout << "Postfix increment called" << endl;}
    Base operator ++ () {count++;  cout << "Prefix increment called" << endl;}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Base operator --(int)  {count--;  cout << "Postfix decrement called" << endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Derived A;
    A++;
    ++A;
    A--;
    return 0;
}
```

The result I get is

```
Constructor called
Postfix increment called
Destructor called
Prefix increment called
Destructor called
Postfix decrement called
Destructor called
Destructor called
```

My question is why the destructor called so many times?

Comment: You do not monitor copy construction (and move semantics) - In other words, the test is flawed

Comment: Where are the returns in the operators? Does it compile (without warnings)

Comment: Yes it compiles without warnings on g++ compiler..

Comment: @Sathish: Missing returns trigger undefined behavior in C++. Anyway, the destructor calls you see is just destruction of temporary `Base` objects *supposedly* returned from your member functions.

Comment: @Sathish It shouldn't compile if you treat warnings as errors: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/008aaf3ef021076a

Comment: Btw You're not returning from your operator functions.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think you misunderstand.  It compiles without warnings, which means with all warnings turned off.  :/  Which is why the first question should always be "what is are your command line arguments".

Comment: @Yakk No I am not confused.  It compiles with warnings and if you treat warnings as errors it wont even compile.

Comment: @NathanOliver try compiling it with all warning disabled: it compiles.  That is another (useless) meaning of "compiling without warnings" that I suspect the OP was using (in effect, at least)

Answer (score 2):

First of all all these operators

```
Base operator ++ (int) {count++;  cout << "Postfix increment called" << endl;}
Base operator ++ () {count++;  cout << "Prefix increment called" << endl;}
Base operator --(int)  {count--;  cout << "Postfix decrement called" << endl;}
```

are invalid because they return nothing though their return types are not void. You should write for example

```
Base operator ++ (int) 
{
    count++;  
    cout << "Postfix increment called" << endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Otherwise the program has undefined behaviour.

As the operators have return type Base then the compiler calls the destructor for the temporary objects that the operators have to return.

All these three expressions

```
A++;
++A;
A--;
```

are in fact temporary objects.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, each of your operators returns a temporary object of type `Base` to the caller. That temporary object is destroyed after each operator call. This destruction is exactly what you observe in your experiments.

However, you forgot to include `return` statements into your operator definitions. Because of that you code has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is passed as a non-reference variable, the compiler creates the variable with the set copy-constructor and destroys it after its scope ends.

To fix that you could pass the variable as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your operators return a `Base`.  Since you do not capture that `Base` it is destroyed at the end of the expression.  Since you have three expressions you are getting three destructor calls.